# How do you know when the frontiers find each other?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-science

Bidirectional search must be able to determine when the frontiers intersect. For
each of the following pairs of searches specify how to determine when the frontiers
intersect:

1. Breadth-first search and depth-bounded depth-first search.
2. Iterative deepening search and depth-bounded depth-first search.
3. A∗ and depth-bounded depth-bounded search.
4. A∗ and A∗

Comment: If you post your homework questions here, post at least whatever code or answers you came up with, instead of asking us to do your work.

Comment: Why is this tagged with artificial intelligence?

Comment: Because such search algorithms are often used in artificial intelligence!?